# loop with a condition in a two dimensional array with Python

Tags: python, arrays, netcdf

I have an array in this form data[values,longitude,latitude] where the size is data[21000,12,13]. The data are daily temperature values for around 50 years in NetCDF format, for an area of 12x13 grids.

I want to extract in a new table the sum of the values for each lon and lat that are greater than 10 and less than 20. I am new in Python so I stacked at the first steps. Here is what I have and of course there is an error:

```
file = netCDF4.Dataset ('/mnt/data/rcp45/tas/merged_rcp45/rcp45_Celsius.nc')

lat  = file.variables['lat'][:]
lon  = file.variables['lon'][:]
data = file.variables['tas'][:]

for i in range(21000):
    if (data[i,:,:]) > 10  and (data[i,:,:]) < 20:
         x = sum(data[i,:,:])
```

**The expected outcome: x[sum_values_conditionally,longitude,latitude]
So I want a table that for the 21000 timesteps and for each grid point (lon-lat), will calculate the sum only of values that matches the conditions. E.g. for the first grid point: x[230,1,1], where 230 is the some of the values > 10 and <20.**

The error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

[the initial dataset looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caU3Z.png)

[this is the lat values - print(lat)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imUZw.png)

[this is the lon values - print(lon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuQvy.png)

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is not very clear to me, could you add a small input example and the expected output ?

Comment: As for the error your code is raising, that's because numpy arrays can't be evaluated to a boolean value as is, you must define a heuristic for the conversion (`any` or `all` methods for instance).

Comment: Hey Paul, I edited, so I hope now is more clear. Probably my code is far away for what I want to achieve... sorry for that

Comment: Still not quite clear what you are trying to get. My interpretation is you want a resulting array with shape (# lon, # lat) whee the value is the sum of all values in the original 1st index that were between 1 and 20. If so, you are looping over the wrong axis. Another recommendation, don't hard code your for loop range, use properties of your array. It may help you to read over `numpy` documentation or examples to understand how to use it. You should be able to do this without the for loop using indexing, and it will be much fast.

Comment: It's a bit clearer, thanks, but I think there's a misunderstanding here. If I understand correctly, your `data` array has shape `(21_000, 12, 13)` and contains temperature recordings. But how do you map a temperature recording to a longitude and latitude ? You don't explain how the temperature recordings are linked to a latitude and a longitude in you `data` array

Comment: The data are daily values so 365 days*60 years so to be exact there are 21910 temperature values. For every gridpoint there is a value for each day. so there are 12*13=156 gridpoints for each day. I will upload a screenshot of the initial data that maybe helps

Comment: What I wanted to know is what are the longitude and latitude associated with each of your gridpoints ? For instance, what is the longitude of the gridpoint in `data[0][0][0]` ?

Comment: The lat lon coordinates are saved in the arrays lat and lon respectively. So in order to plot the field i was thinking to do something like this after                                                     
x,y = m(*np.meshgrid(lon,lat))

x,y = m(lon, lat)

cs = m.contourf(x,y,data[0,:,:], clevs, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, extend='both')

Comment: So your `lon` array has shape `(12,)` and your `lat` array has shape `(13,)` ?

Comment: No..both arrays have the same shape (12,13), so a 2D array

Comment: I don't get it, if you're workin with a grid, the longitude should be the same for points in the same column right ? Can you add a screenshot of the values contained in `lon` and `lat` ?

Comment: yes it is complicated, especially if you are new... I just added the screenshots

Comment: If you don't mind I can send you also the .nc file to have a more clear look. Can somehow attached it to the post?

Comment: No need to but are you aware that all your longitude and latitude values are greater than 20 ? There is no value between 10 and 20 so what you want to achieve doesn't make much sense :/ I posted an answer but you will get an array full of zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to your question is:

```py
file = netCDF4.Dataset ('/mnt/data/rcp45/tas/merged_rcp45/rcp45_Celsius.nc')

lat  = file.variables['lat'][:]
lon  = file.variables['lon'][:]
data = file.variables['tas'][:]

summed_values = np.zeros((12, 13))

for grid_index, grid in enumerate(data):
    for lon_index, lon_column in enumerate(grid):
        for lat_index, value in enumerate(lon_column):
            if  10 < value and value < 20:
                summed_values[lon_index][lat_index] += value

n_years = data.shape[0] // 365
summed_values_per_year = np.zeros((n_years + 1, 12, 13))

for grid_index, grid in enumerate(data):
    for lon_index, lon_column in enumerate(grid):
        for lat_index, value in enumerate(lon_column):
            if  10 < value and value < 20:
                year = grid_index // 365
                summed_values_per_year [year][lon_index][lat_index] += value
```

Comment: I just tried this. The problem is that with the conditions I want to mask the data and not the lat lon. So it returns an 1d array with .0 .0 .0 .0  and so on... I tried also this : mask = (data > 10) & (data < 20) 


new_data = data[mask] 

summed_values = np.sum(new_data) # shape: (21910)    which is closer to what I want but this way I think I lose the connection between data-lon-lat

Comment: As I said in a comment under your question, there is no value between 10 and 20 in your `lon` and `lat` arrays, that is why you get an array full of zeros. I still don't understand what you expect to be your final result: 

a) do you want an array containing, for each day, the sum of the temperatures in grid points where 10 < longitude < 20 and 10 < latitude < 20

b) or an array containing, for each grid point that has longitude and latitude between 10 and 20, the sum of all temperatures ? Either way, you don't have any gridpoint that has longitude and latitude between 10 and 20

Comment: I can understand the confusion. The answer is none of the above. I want an array containing, for the whole period, the sum of the temperatures in all the grid points where 10 < data < 20. So the mask has to be applied somehow in the data (values) and not to lon lat.

Comment: Ok, I think the way you formulated the question is a bit misleading but I think I understand now. I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: I am so sorry for that. Your answer works perfect! One additional question; If I want to calculate the sum for each year (60 years in total) instead of the whole 60-years period, I just have to put one more for loop?

Comment: No worries :)  If you want the sum for each year, it's a bit more complex because you would have to take into account leap years, but if you don't care,  I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It is reaaaally helpful! Do you know if I can export the final array now again in NetCDF format?

Comment: I am not familiar with the netCDF4 package but having a look at its [documentation](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/) might be a good start to find the answer to your question!